# Why is this sentence wrong? "I looked at our watch"

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, possessives

While studying English by watching a video, I encountered the following sentence:

> ”I looked at our watch"

in the video it said, the sentence was wrong because **"I"** is singular and **"our"** is plural.

If I'm using **"Our"** as an adjective describing the watch, does that make the sentence correct?

Comment: Whose watch is it?

Comment: That's a confusing example sentence. There is nothing wrong grammatically with "I looked at our watch". The only thing that is wrong with it is that it doesn't make much sense: a watch is typically a personal possession, so it's unclear what a phrase like "our watch" means. That doesn't make it ungrammatical. Whether or not it is "correct" depends on what you mean by that.

Comment: In Italian "[orologio](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orologio)" can be translated as [wrist] watch, which you wear on your wrist and [wall] clock, which often is hung on a wall. If it is a [wrist] watch, then its owner will normally say "my watch", it is unlikely that a watch worn by somebody is owned by two or more people. Do not confuse a "watch" with a "clock".

Comment: *I took our son to school this morning*. What's the problem?

Comment: It's grammatically correct. I can think of some situations in which it makes sense too. Presumably, your video was an exercise after a specific set of beginner tutorials matching basic pronouns based on number, and that's why it (incorrectly) declared it wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I understand "our watch" is a weird sentence and how uncommon is for people to share watches,

Comment: I just wondered if I say, for example, "I cheered at our team"  because the way it was explained to me was to stay consistent if I use a singular pronoun I have to stay with singular but "our" can be either plural or adjective, I guess?. In that case is ok for me to use "I" and "our"  in the same sentence as long as "our" is used as an adjective, not as plural.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. *Our* denotes possession by more than one person. It is a [plural possessive determiner](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/our).

Comment: I would recommend just forgetting that video and that explanation about "staying consistent". There is no special rule preventing you from using "our" in the same sentence as "I", no matter how you use it. The rule is just that you only use "our" when you mean "our", and likewise you should ony use "my" when you mean "my", and so on. ”I looked at our watch" is wrong if you mean to express "I looked at my watch". It's correct if you mean to express the (odd) situation of looking at a watch that is owned by you and someone else.

Comment: You could also say "I looked at his watch" or "I looked at their watch" or "I looked at your watch." The only time when "consistency" is relevant is when you are dealing with pronouns that have less straightforward and more vague definitions, like "it", "they", or "one", or when you're dealing with tricky words like "any", "each" and "all". And even in those contexts the consistency "rules" aren't always applied by native English speakers, so I wouldn't recommend prioritizing learning these "rules" if you are a beginning or intermediate student of English.

Comment: I have not seen the video, but if the duty officer on board a ship said it, it makes perfect sense to talk about "our watch" - meaning the crew.

Comment: Only if you're a Siamese twin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you share the watch with another person - if you co-own it, e.g. - then it would make sense.  Otherwise, you would say *"I looked at my watch*".

With other items, this might make more sense, e.g. "I walked to our car", "I ate some of our watermelon", "I slept in our bed", ...